# strange message from phone number but it was not sms

Tags: sms

Today I received strange message. My phone vibred and on locked screen on top bar I saw identical icon like when I receving a traditional text. 
When I unlocked screen than I saw something like popup (or modal) but fixed to bottom. In header was a phone number. In center was a text but not all it was truncated. In bottom section was two buttons cancel and save.
unfortunately i pressed cancel button and now I can't find this message in system. 
I thought that it traditional sms so I didn't save this. 
there was something about the administrator of my personal data in the content, so it's important to me
Anybody can tell me where I can found this message or what kind of message it is? From network operator?

Comment: That's called a [flash SMS](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flash+SMS).

Comment: https://www.guidingtech.com/53398/view-android-notifications-history